# Silverlight Security exception

Tags: security, silverlight

I get the following error when I run a Silverlight application in Windows 8.1 under Visual Studio 2013.

```
    Stack Trace:
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
```

I created a clientaccesspolicy.xml file with the following. I still get the same error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
    <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
            <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
                <domain uri="*"/>
            </allow-from>
            <grant-to>
                <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
            </grant-to>
        </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Any more settings that I need to add so I don't get the security errors.

Comment: Please could you add the code to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that I did not put the clientaccesspolicy.xml file at the right folder and that was causing the error.